# Difference between 'scope:setting(Key, Value)' and 'setting(scope:Key, Value)'

Tags: module, prolog, swi-prolog, setting

In SWI-Prolog's [settings library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/settings.pl), is there a different between the following:

- `scope:set_setting(Key, Value)` and `set_setting(scope:Key, Value)`
- `scope:setting(Key, Value)` and `setting(scope:Key, Value)`
- `:- scope:setting(Key, Type, Default, Doc)` and `:- setting(scope:Key, Type, Default, Doc)`

In addition: can `scope` be anything but `user` and a currently loaded module name?

Answer (score 0):

> Difference between `scope:setting(Key, Value)` and `setting(scope:Key, Value)`

`settings` are local to the module and they cannot be called as a predicate and  can only be declared as a directive.

`setting(Key, Value)` only enumerates the settings of the current module. All settings can be enumerated using setting(Module:Name, Value). This predicate is deterministic if `Name` is ground.

`set_settings` changes the settings.